# Ubuntu : how to install matplotlib with python3.2 (freetype issue)

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.x, matplotlib, freetype

In this thread:

[How to install matplotlib with Python3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605847/how-to-install-matplotlib-with-python3-2)

the following is adviced:

> git clone https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib
>
> cd matplotlib
>
> python3 setup.py build
>
> sudo python3 setup.py install

but this does not work for me, as I get:

> - The following required packages can not be built:
> - freetype

I do not know what freetype is, but it does not seem to be in aptitude or pip.

I found the sources here:
https://github.com/rougier/freetype-py

but installing failed:

> ```
> byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/freetype/__init__.py to
> ```
>
> **init**.cpython-32.pyc
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/freetype/**init**.py", line 39
>           raise RuntimeError, 'Freetype library not found'
>                             ^
>       SyntaxError: invalid syntax

but apparently that was to be expected, as freetype does not seem to be ok with python3.2:

https://code.google.com/p/freetype-py/issues/detail?id=11

As it seems to me other people manage to use matplotlib with python3, anything I am missing ?

ps : this did not work :
[`Sudo pip install matplotlib` fails to find freetype headers. [OS X Mavericks / 10.9]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20572366/sudo-pip-install-matplotlib-fails-to-find-freetype-headers-os-x-mavericks)

Comment: This might belong to [superuser](http://superuser.com/) instead of SO.

Comment: sorry, did not get that

Comment: @Vince: superuser is another StackExchange site; SO is StackOverflow, this site

Comment: Consider installing your packages using [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip), [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) or [conda](http://www.continuum.io/blog/conda).

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.
My mistake was to look simply to look for a package called "freetype" instead of "libfreetype".

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/freetype