# fatal error: freetype/config/ftheader.h

Tags: c++, g++, freetype, freetype2

I am trying to use freeglut2 for rendering text in OpenGL. When I included the following header,

`#include <freetype2/ft2build.h>`

it gives the following error :

`/usr/local/include/freetype2/ft2build.h:37:38: fatal error: freetype/config/ftheader.h: No such file or directory`

But when I go to `/usr/local/include/freetype2/freetype/config` , I found the file ftheader.h.

Please help me in figuring out the issue. Thank you.

I went to the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20572366/sudo-pip-install-matplotlib-fails-to-find-freetype-headers-os-x-mavericks) but nothing worked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your compiler searches for includes in `/usr/local/include`, so when you do:

```
#include <freetype2/ft2build.h>
```

it finds `/usr/local/include/freetype2/ft2build.h`

but this file tries to include `freetype/config/ftheader.h` and there is no

```
/usr/local/include/freetype/config/ftheader.h
```

but

```
/usr/local/include/freetyp2/freetype/config/ftheader.h
```

So you shall pass `-I/usr/local/include/freetyp2` to your compiler and do a

```
#include <ft2build.h>
```

to be correct.

If your system supports it - use `pkg-config` utility, which can provide all compilations flag, e.g.:

```
$ pkg-config --cflags freetype2
-I/usr/include/freetype2  

$ pkg-config --libs freetype2
-lfreetype
```

Comment: When your system has `pkg-config` utility you can use it to automatically add necessary flags for your compiler. First example gives you flags for compilation, second - for linking (on my system).

Comment: It gives Unknown option -I/usr/include/freetype2

Comment: @udhy: You just type `pkg-config --cflags freetype2`. Line below is produced by utility. You should pass it to your compiler.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was very nice explanation.

Answer (score 2):

From reading this documentation: http://freetype.org/freetype2/docs/tutorial/step1.html#section-1

You need to add /usr/local/include/freetype2 to your include path.

Then you include ft2build.h with:

```
#include <ft2build.h>
```

Then when ft2build.h includes freetype/config/ftheader.h it will look in freetype2 directory in the include path and find it.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how do I add `/usr/local/include/freetype2`